# Magmi DataPump integration (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magmi, magenta

I can't figure out how Magmi DataPump works.
I have successful installed Magmi with test script (/magmi/integration/scripts/import/test.php):

```
require_once("../../../../inc/magmi_defs.php");
require_once("../../inc/magmi_datapump.php");
$dp=Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");
$dp->beginImportSession("default","create");

$testitem=array("name"=>"test","sku"=>"testsku","price"=>"10.00","attribute_set"=>"Default","store"=>"admin","description"=>"ingested with Datapump API");

$dp->ingest($testitem);

$dp->endImportSession();
```

As I set in code "default","create" - I run default task with "create new items & update existing ones" but in admin panel no products :(

How to debug and run these scripts? In the official documentation I see instructions for creating them but not about solving problems :(

Comment: Any solutions about that?

Comment: @mahmoudismail nop, left Magmi. I made custom "parser" for my case, works like a charm.